# ASP.NET Core MVC Model Binding Bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm having some trouble with ASP.NET Core's [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1).  Basically I'm just trying to bind some POSTed json to an object model with nested properties.  Minimal code is provided below for a single button that, when pressed, will POST to a Controller action method via XMLHttpRequest.  The action method takes a single model class parameter with the `[FromBody]` attribute.

**Model:**

```
public class OuterModel {
    public string OuterString { get; set; }
    public int OuterInt { get; set; }
    public InnerModel Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerModel {
    public string InnerString { get; set; }
    public int InnerInt { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller {

    [HttpPost("models/")]
    public IActionResult Save([FromBody] OuterModel viewModel) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        // Return an appropriate response
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Razor markup for a "submit" button:**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-2">
        @{ string url = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Save), "Home"); }
        <button id="post-btn" data-post-url="@url">POST</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript to submit (DOES NOT bind):**

```
document.getElementById("post-btn").addEventListener("click", e => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("timeout", () => console.error("Timeout"));
        xhr.addEventListener("error", () => console.error("Error"));
        xhr.addEventListener("load", () => console.log(`Status: ${xhr.status} ${xhr.statusText}`));
        xhr.open("POST", e.target.dataset.postUrl);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            "OuterString": "outer",
            "OuterInt": 1,
            "Inner.InnerString": "inner",
            "Inner.InnerInt": 5
        }));
    });
```

Looking at that JavaScript, I would expect the `Inner.*` json property names to bind correctly, given this line from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#how-model-binding-works):

> Model binding looks for the pattern *parameter_name.property_name* to bind values to properties. If it doesn't find matching values of this form, it will attempt to bind using just the property name.

But it doesn't; the `OuterModel.Inner` property in the action method ends up `null`.  The following json *does* bind correctly, however:

**JavaScript to submit (DOES bind):**

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    "OuterString": "outer",
    "OuterInt": 1,
    "Inner": {
        "InnerString": "inner",
        "InnerInt": 5
    }
}));
```

So I can use this code to achieve the model binding that I need, I'm just confused as to why the first JavaScript *didn't* work.  Was I not using the correct naming convention for nested properties?  Some clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: If the data is `Inner.InnerString: "inner"` then send it using the default `contentType` (i.e. `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) and do not stringify it

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Can I still put `[FromBody]` on the action method parameter if I use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?  I want this action method to be exposed as a REST API that accepts json.

Comment: Its not required (but not sure if you must omit it - cannot test at the moment). When you have `[FromBody]`, the ModelBinder reads the `ContentType` fromthe headers to determine which formatter to use, and for `application/json` it uses the `JsonInputFormatter` (using Json.NET), but your first example is not valid json for nested properties which is why it will not bind (its not a bug)

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the "*parameter_name.property_name*" rule from the quoted docs only applies for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request bodies.  I thought that json requests with object keys following that naming convention would also be bound, but apparently not.  Makes sense, but the docs could be a little clearer.

Comment: It cannot bind because there is no such thing as  'dot' notation in json - its just a collection of key-value pairs, so "Inner.InnerString": "inner" means bind to a property named `Inner.InnerString` (which of course fails because that is not even a valid name in c#)

Comment: Right, I just assumed (naively) that mvc did some kind of reflection magic to map a json key with the dot-notation to a nested c# property, as it does with form values. But obviously that would be tricky if a json request included both dot-notation *and* nested object keys, which is probably why they only bind the nested keys